# Can we stick the sticky header of sectionList (or a scrollView) to a relative position to the top of the scrollview?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When we scroll the sectionList we can stick the sticky header at the top of the scrollview.

But what I need is to set a margin between the sticky header and the top of the scrollview i.e, leave a gap between the top of the scrollview.

Does any one know how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS the way I handled it was to add two more props along with the horizontal margins

```
      contentContainerStyle={{
        marginHorizontal: 16,
      }}
      ListHeaderComponent={<View style={{ height: 16 }} />}
      ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ height: 16 }} />}
```

This ensures that the header will stick to the top and won't bleed content through.